# How to check if a force Directed node is collapsed

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm working on a force directed tree. And I wanted to check on a hit events if the target dataItem is collapsed or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I just found it. So for someone who would cross the same pb. The answer is in the event.target 's isActive property